# Eloquent query: sum() returning zeros?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using the following DB statement to try to qualify a certain set of stats to be summarized.
It consistently returns zeros (when I know there are values in all the matching fields from doing direct SQL queries into the db).

```
$this->count = \DB::table('stat_points')->where('location_id',$location)->where('date',$date)->where('fieldname',$varname)->sum('fieldvalue');
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That looks like it should work. If you remove the wheres, do you get a result then?

Comment: I think I was being mislead by hitting a single case in which the correct answer was a row of zeros.  ;-P

Comment: Ah, classic :) well, at least you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I jiggled things around a bit and came up with this, which is working fine.

```
$sum = \DB::table('stat_points')
        ->select(\DB::raw("SUM(fieldvalue)"))
        ->where('date',$date)
        ->where('location_id',$location)
        ->where('fieldname',$varname)
        ->get();
```

Comment: You could skip the `select` and have it in the `get` to shorten it a little bit. `get([DB::raw('SUM(fieldvalue)')])`